# Excel VBA For each nested loop

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, foreach, vba

I am trying to build an Excel workbook that takes data from one sheet, and fills out another based on a system name. I am having a problem with the first for next loop. It works for the first system, but if there are more than one item in the system it just stops working. The second for each loop works great. Is there a better way to run my first loop. I try an if the first For each variable matches the second for each then increment, but the code says the next Inspectcell does not have a for each. The system name is always in column C and starts at C7

```
Sub fillthereport()

Dim xx As Variant, ws As Variant, yy As Variant
Dim ws2 As Variant, xxx As Variant, yyy As Variant
Dim rowed As Integer, b As Integer


'Dim MySht As Worksheet
Dim MyPic As Shape
Dim MyLeft As Single, MyTop As Single
Dim conv As Variant
Dim item As Variant
Dim picnum As Variant
Dim mergecells As String, mergecells2 As String, mergecolor As String
Dim horstart As Variant, horend As Variant
Dim verstart As Variant, verend As Variant
Dim Inspectcell As Range, reportcell As Range



'worksheets loop operator
ws = 1

'worksheets loop operator to
ws2 = 6

'row designator from
xx = 7

'column designator from
yy = 3

'row designator to
xxx = 68

'column designator to
yyy = 37

'This is not the variable you are looking for
 b = 0
 'These are the variables you are looking for
 yel = 0
 bl = 0
 re = 0

 Folderpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 reportcell = Worksheets("inspection Data").Range("C7")
 'make extra sheets in the report to be filled
 For Each Inspectcell In Worksheets("inspection Data").Range("C7:C18")
    If Inspectcell = reportcell Then

        Worksheets(ws2).Select

        Worksheets(ws2).Range("A60:AY114").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(ws2).Range("A115:AY169").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets(ws2).Range("A170:AY224").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    'reportcell = Inspectcell

          For Each reportcell In Worksheets("inspection Data").Range("C7:C18")
              If reportcell = Inspectcell Then

             '(This is about 110 lines of code that work great)
                  xx = xx + 1
                  b = b + 1
           'worksheets loop operator
          'ws = ws + 1

          'worksheets loop operator to
          'ws2 = ws2 + 1

          'column designator from
          'yy = yy + 1

          'row designator to
                  If Not b Mod 3 = 0 Then

                      xxx = xxx + 16

                  Else

                      xxx = xxx + 23

                  End If


              Else  'If xx = 15 Then

                  Exit For

              End If

               'xxx = xxx + 22
          Next reportcell

          ws2 = ws2 + 1
  'Else
    'Exit for
 End if

Next Inspectcell
```

Comment: Is this the exact code? you are missing and End If right before the last Line of code. Also you can just remove the Else -> Exit For statement because it would End the Loop completely if the next Row doesnt have the information you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That fixed the for each error.

Comment: Now I cannot get Reportcell to take a value to test in the first "if then". Is there a better way to test if Inspectcell is going to repeat a system name or number? The system can be any alpha numeric code 3 or 4 digits long.

Comment: This is because at the beginning you are assigning reportcell the value from C7, and then on the second loop, you are using reportcell as the place holder for the second loop. You should use a different variable for that.